# Refernce or link doesn't work in Flowplayer captions plugin

Tags: flowplayer, subtitle, closed-captions

I'm working with Flowplayer captions plugin http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/flash/captions.html and I need references/links in subtitles. When I've built into srt file link like `<a href="http://flowplayer.org/">click this link to flowplayer.org</a>`
then the flowplayer stuck on parse processing and last message was only

> org.flowplayer.captions::Caption : captions file loaded, parsing cuepoints

Please prompt me how to resolve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by commented out some piece of code in source code. This code checks for XML subtitle format and fails when it reads linked html code.